# istreambuf_iterator with structs

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm having a hard time getting istreambuf_iterator working with other types than char. We all know you can transform a stream into a range like this:

```
istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifstream("some_file")) //now we have an iterator that reads chars each step.
```

I have a binary stream of structs, not chars. So I need to be able to do this:

```
istreambuf_iterator<MyStruct>(ifstream("some_file"))
```

I want to easily iterate over all the MyStruct's in the stream. This I cannot get to work since ifstream is an istream which is an `basic_istream<char>` which is only working with `istreambuf_iterator<char>`, not `istreambuf_iterator<MyStruct>`.

I have already written my own iterator but I wanted to use the STD iterator because it seemed perfect. Why did they make things like this? Why can I not iterate over structs in an ifstream using istreambuf_iterator?

Edit:

People have suggested using istream_iterator with a custom implementation of operator>>. This will work but for my specific use I need to read a specific amount of MyStruct's, not until EOF. The stream contains, say 5, MyStruct's and then more data that is not supposed to be read as MyStructs. So I need to create the "end-iterator" for the range by offsetting the "begin-iterator" like this:

```
auto begin = istream_iterator<MyStruct>(the_istream);
auto end = istream_iterator<MyStruct>(the_istream) + 5;
```

But this I don't know if it's possible.

It would be nice to have a fully standard STL iterator which has all these features and it seems they could easily have covered all these use cases if the standard iterators were somewhat more thought through. I guess the shortest and easiest solution is to keep using my custom iterator.

Comment: Why are you not using `istream_iterator`?

Comment: Because the operator>> is not defined for MyStruct. Maybe an overload + istream_iterator is the closest I can get? Any binary_istream_iterator that automatically gets how to read MyStruct?

Comment: Why don't you make a `istream& operator>>(istream&, MyStruct&)`? That is what you should be doing.

Answer (score 1):

`ifstream` is a typedef for `basic_ifstream<char>`.  Since you are using a stream which is typed as if it contains `char`s, it's not surprising that you can only iterate over `char`s.  You might think to try this (I did):

```
istreambuf_iterator<MyStruct>(basic_ifstream<MyStruct>("some_file"))
```

But it won't work, because it requires a `char_traits` class for `MyStruct`, and `char_traits` in turn requires defining an `int_type` which in this case would be an integer that holds a `MyStruct`.  Presumably `MyStruct` can't be stored in any integer type, so we're out of luck.

I assume you already know you can overload `operator>>(istream&, MyStruct&)`....

Comment: My point is that, I already implemented an iterator that is constructed from an std::istream (which is basic_stream<char>) but acts as it contains MyStruct's. Using this iterator I can use the C++11 range based for to loop over all the MyStructs while they are read on the fly from the stream.

But I want to use istreambuf_iterator instead. They could easily have made an iterator like the one I did, but they went for some unusable variant instead. I cannot figure out how to use it.

Comment: @user1284878: So what's your question then?  Is it "Why are the C++ standards people stupid?"

Comment: Pretty much yes. I mean, they could easily made istreambuf_iterator A LOT more useful if it could just take an istream. In my iterator I just istream.read((char *) &myStruct, sizeof(MyStruct)) and return it when the iterator is dereferenced. istreambuf_iterator could have done the same.

Comment: Do you know of any Boost iterator like the one I did, or any C++17 improvements? I don't like adding custom iterators when C++ is like 99% iterator templates.

Comment: @user1284878: Don't feel bad about adding custom iterators--they're very useful.  The whole STL is practically an invitation to write  your own iterators, though very few people actually do.  Being taught this many years ago was a revelation for me.